# getting 405 method not allowed

Tags: django, post

getting the 405 error, cant say why. the Url seems to check, the POST method.... what am I missing here.

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from tweets.views import Index, Profile, PostTweet
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view()),
]
```

**html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <form method = 'POST'>{% csrf_token %}
      <!-- <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  fieldWrapper"> -->
        {{ form.text.errors }} 
        {{ form.text }}
      <!-- </div> -->
      {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
       <button type="submit"  value="post it">Post
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="col-md-12 column">
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
    <div class="well">
    <span>{{ tweet.text }}</span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div> -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**:

```
class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method =='POST':
          print('post')
        return HttpResponse('posted')
```

Still getting the above error no matter what I do.
Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you forgot to close the `button` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your post method name in view, it should be `post` not `Post`. Also need to update the method signature like following:

```
class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # renamed it post instead of Post
        if request.method =='POST':
          print(post)
        return HttpResponse('posted')
```

Also update the form like this:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <!-- <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  fieldWrapper"> -->
    {{ form.text.errors }} 
    {{ form.text }}
  <!-- </div> -->
  {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
   <button type="submit"  value="post it">Post
</form>
```

#### Update

You need to provide a get method to the view to get [http get](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) functionality(I am using [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to show the html):

```
class PostTweet(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # renamed it post instead of Post
        if request.method =='POST':
          print(post)
        return HttpResponse('posted')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = YourForm()
        return render(request, 'your_html.html', {'form': form})
```

You need to define a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) as well(if you havn't) to render a form in html.

Finally, I don't know why you taking such hassle to render a form, where you can simply use a [FormView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) which will do everything for you. For example:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.CharField()


class PostTweet(FormView):
     form_class = YourForm
     template_name = "path/to/template.html"

     def form_valid(self, form):
         print(form.cleaned_data)  # it will show all the data submitted from the form
         return super(YourFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

As I can see, your urls are not defined properly using regex. You can update it like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view()),  # or any other variable
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
]
```

So when you hit to see `PostTweet`, then use `/user/<any_username>/post/` where `any_username` can be any username you want to use.

Comment: Followed your advice. No avail.

Comment: Can you please share the updated code in your question? I am not sure what is going wrong here. BTW, have you looked into FormView section?

Comment: @AlonBen-Ari please rename `YourFormView` to `PostTweet` and link it to the urls

Comment: I added the code up above starting with 'This is what I got following your advice.' Still same error. 405 method not allowed.

Comment: Well, I think there has been a misunderstanding, its my fault. I named `YourFormView` as an example, where it should be `PostTweet`. I have updated my answer

Comment: urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/$', Profile.as_view()),
    url(r'^user/(\w+)/post/$', PostTweet.as_view())
     
] No  difference in result

Comment: @AlonBen-Ari I just noticed, your urls are not properly defined. I have added an updated url pattern at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Thank you ruddra, no change I m afraid. still 405 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <form method = 'post'>{% csrf_token %}                         #<-- POST to post
      <!-- <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  fieldWrapper"> -->
        {{ form.text.errors }} 
        {{ form.text }}
      <!-- </div> -->
      {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
       <button type="submit"  value="post it">Post</button>        #add this
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="col-md-12 column">
    {% for tweet in tweets %}
    <div class="well">
    <span>{{ tweet.text }}</span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div> -->
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: no difference. html is forgiving to closing/not clong tags. besides the error is a 405 error.

Comment: @AlonBen-Ari Why are you not using **Generic CBV's**?

Comment: @AlonBen-Ari Classed Based Views!

Comment: How is this relevant to the 405 error I am getting?.